# xamarin for mac couldnot create or open xamarin.form project

Tags: macos, xamarin

[image]

> MarshalError: [NOTE: this exception originated in the server.]
>   Couldn't get signature for selector 'supportedRuntimes'

Comment: Same problem here :/ Did you manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error, and it seems it was because some Mac updates (I had just updated the SO and XCode), I updated Xamarin (Xamarin Studio > Check for Updates...) and it worked just fine.